# MERGE doesn't work in SQL 2008 R2 when SQL 2005 is installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

To install our application we use a setup created ad hoc, which (together with many other operations) runs some scripts, including a script that contains the MERGE clause. The minimum requirement is to use MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

A customer get an error when trying to execute the script described above, which says:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'MERGE'.
```

I'm trying to figure out why, since he is using a SQL 2008 R2 database. I've discovered that in the same machine there's a SQL 2005 installation. Could this cause a conflict? Can this has something to do with compatibility level? If I try to run the same script via the SQL 2008 R2 SSMS it works.

Comment: I guess your client does not use `;` Add at the beginning `;MERGE ..... ;` `The MERGE statement requires a semicolon (;) as a statement terminator. Error 10713 is raised when a MERGE statement is run without the terminator.`

Comment: Maybe there's actually a syntax error in your script.  How can we know without seeing it?